# css font-family issue with chromium

Tags: css, chromium

This css definition :

`* {font-family: 'Lucida console', monospace;}`

is correctly interpretated by firefox.

With ubuntu-chromium (v18.0.1025..), in order to get the same fonts, I wrote

`* {font-family: monospace 'Lucida console';}` (yes, without the comma)

You can try this [live example](http://mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/#B/ZVBNSwMxED3HXzFtDwVx2YIX2UQvq+BB0IMgHtN8dINJpiTZ6rr0v5tk9eRc3sDMe/PesNX9c//6/vIAQ3L27oItQNiguMxImFOJgxh4iCrdrsekm5t1HcQ0WVU6skc5wbzn4uMQcPSyEWgxdLDRtajj4WB8B9e73fGL4kkFbfGzg8FIqTw9F41LmDX61GjujJ06cOgxHrlQV7B9GoWR2QT6iFZtASjU3Wi+VVHNokDPhBQdaU4wwz8vm77vKZRLrP0zztrfkKwEqJkyu+CjshbhDYOVsKqcZcDaZTMzy5t+AA==) with both browsers (code embedded inside the link).

How to make "monospace lucida console" available for both ? Thanks.

Comment: `* {font-family: 'Lucida console', monospace ; font-size: 30px; }` seems to  work fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: not seeing any difference there.  `monospace 'Lucida console'` seems to get parsed to ignore the `monospace` part and still use `'Lucida console'` but `'Lucida console', monospace` does the same thing in Chrome (v 23.0.1271.97 m)

Answer (score 0):

I found the beginning of an answer.

The Firefox (22.0) console talked :

```
[13:03:08,615] downloadable font: download failed 
  (font-family: "lucida_consoleregular" [...])
  bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
  source: http://www.goto.com/font/lucida_console-webfont.ttf 
  @ http://www.goto.com/css/style.css
  source: [...] lucida_console-webfont.woff
[13:03:08,615] downloadable font: no supported format found
```

The DNS aiming at this website is redirected from two URL :
one prefixed by "**w3**." and the other by "**www**." The font path is the stylesheet is a relative path, but the server root URI is unique, be it www or w3

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lucida_consoleregular';
    src: url('../fonts/lucida_console-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lucida_console-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lucida_console-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lucida_console-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

no error occurs when calling the right prefix related to the correct root URI

On the other hand, Ubuntu-Chromium (now 28.0) and Opera (12.16) have no problem with that.